# How to make 6 threads runs multiple tasks sequentially

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
public class ProcessImpl implements Process {


    @Override
    public void process() {

        List<Callable<Boolean>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
            tasks.add(createTask(x));
        }


        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) { //for each group, there are 6 groups
            //this is a sequential executor
            //DefaultThreadExecutor extends AbstractThreadExecutor
            ExecutorService threadExecutor = new DefaultThreadExecutor();
            try {
                threadExecutor.invokeAll(tasks); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    private Callable<Boolean> createTask(final int i) {
        Callable<Boolean> task = new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Performing task " + i + " on thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                return true;
            }
        };
        return task;
    }

}
```

In this piece of code, `threadExecutor.invokeAll(tasks);`, tasks are performed on `Main` thread. It prints something like this:

```
Performing task 1 on thread - main
Performing task 2 on thread - main
Performing task 3 on thread - main
Performing task 4 on thread - main
Performing task 5 on thread - main
Performing task 1 on thread - main
```

I am looking to have **a Thread per group, so 6 threads** in total and each thread should complete the 5 tasks sequentially.

How do I change `process()` in order to achieve this? So each thread are all up at the same time processing the 5 tasks sequentially with each thread **not waiting for any other threads.**

Result (which may vary with random sleep which I will introduce)

```
Performing task 1 on thread - group1
Performing task 1 on thread - group2
Performing task 2 on thread - group2
Performing task 1 on thread - group3
Performing task 2 on thread - group1
Performing task 3 on thread - group2
```

Comment: Sequentially means they process one after the other, meaning task 2 have to wait for task 1. Maybe you don't use the right word here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
@Override
    public void process() {

        List<Callable<Boolean>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
            tasks.add(createTask(x));
        }

  ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5 or 6 depending on how much threads you want to run in parallel);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) { //for each group, there are 6 groups
            //this is a sequential executor
            //DefaultThreadExecutor extends AbstractThreadExecutor

            try {
                service.invokeAll(tasks); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

To initialize yourExecutor Service. Now all your callable will be queued against so much threads that CPUs you have available.

Comment: Hi - I want the 5 tasks(which represent lets say 200m in a relay race of 1000m) to be run by 6 threads which lets say are the teams in the race. so each thread runs the 5 tasks meaning they complete the event.

Comment: Well just replace the Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()  with 6 and you are ready :)

Comment: Wait a second! 5 tasks 6 threads ???? How comes you need to have 1 Callable 1 thread relationship. There is no way to execute 5 tasks with 6 threads. :)))

Comment: If I understand you case correcty you have 6 groups of 5 tasks. And you want for each group all 5 tasks to be running in different thread. For this purpose your threadPool needs to be initialized with 5. One more thing, the way you have the current code you might not be able to actually observe the multithreading. Put some more time consuming thing into the call method of the Callable like Thread.sleep(somePeriod)

Comment: Yes,  Im adding some random time delays in call method. Could you update the answer, show what you mean by "initialize threadPool with 5" ? Do you mean 6 for the 6 groups? `ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);` can perform lets say `task2` multiple times

Comment: No I mean 5 if you set 5 this amount of threads will be responsible to execute your tasks. After one group is executed the next one comes and so on.... 6 times.

Comment: ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);  Because what you essentially want is to ensure that the 5 tasks are executed in 5 parallel threads. You dont need 6th thread you need 5.

Comment: Im looking to have each of the 6 threads (teams), run the 5 tasks sequentially (1 tasks represents player completing 200m, before passing baton to next player...task2 and so on...). is your suggestion doing this?